# Можно ли использовать хэш функции без защиты от коллизий? Т.е. просто надеясь на то что коллизия не произойдёт

Tags: php, хеширование, md5, fingerprint

Или же всё таки это неверный подход? И нужно всегда строить хэш талицы с соответствующей проверкой.

Вопрос не касается темы шифрования, речь просто про получение уникальных отпечатков.

Comment: Все так и делают в общем-то) Только вот для md5 и sha1 давно научились создавать коллизии искусственно

Comment: @andreymal Можно дату добавлять конкатенацией, тогда даже если хэш совпадёт, то дата будет отличаться.